# How can I refer to an Owner of a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Visual Studio 2013, Visual C#, Windows Form Applications.

I am interested in two Form classes. The **AfterTheGameForm.cs** and the **TheGameForm.cs**.

The first one pop's up only if the user clicks a button in the second one.

```
AfterTheGameForm afterTheGameForm = new AfterTheGameForm();
afterTheGameForm.Show(this);
```

So it's clear that TheGameForm is the Owner of AfterTheGameForm. And here lies my problem... **In the AfterTheGameForm class** **I want to refer to the Owner class** in order to use its specific methods. I know for sure that the Owner is of type TheGameForm and I am trying to cast:

```
TheGameForm gForm = (TheGameForm)this.Owner;
        if(gForm!=null){               
            MessageBox.Show(theGameForm.CheckedRadioButton);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("theGameForm==null");
        }
```

I also tried this cast:

```
TheGameForm gForm = this.Owner as TheGameForm;
```

The gForm object **is null!** How is that possible?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to diagnose problems in your code. That said, from the little bit of code you did post, it's apparent that your `AfterTheGameForm` is very tightly coupled to the `TheGameForm`, i.e. it is aware of the type and accesses specific members of the class directly. A better design would use events or other abstractions to allow the forms to interact without actually being tied to each other in that way. In other words, `AfterTheGameForm` shouldn't even need the `Owner` property to be set for the right thing to happen here.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I do not know how to design good code, that's my problem! :) I found that solution with the owner and tried to use it.

Comment: Another way to find it is `TheGameForm gForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<TheGameForm>().FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That probably because you're accessing it in the constructor. The `Owner` is set after the constructor. Try the `Load` event.

Comment: Why would the original code be trying to use `Owner` in the constructor? Presumably the OP at least understands that since the constructor has to return before he can even call the `Show()` method, the `Owner` property couldn't possibly be set there.

Comment: Actually the fact that the Owner is set AFTER the constructor probably helps!

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen It did worked also with the Load event!