# How to check if form is called from another form C#

Tags: c#

I have `Form1` and in that form, i have this code

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

So now is my question: how to know if `form2` is called by the way like that
in Button event in `form2`?
In button event in `form2`, I want to check if `ShowDialog()` is called ***FROM FORM1 (NOT FROM ANOTHER FORM)***, if button is clicked, `form2` is closed!

Comment: Add just a parameter to the constructor of `form2` or set a property (or a method) in `form2`

Comment: can u type example code? i'm don't know how to do as you say

Comment: Look at my answer.

Comment: This may be a duplicate (or close to it): [How to get reference to the Calling Form from function without parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46366099/608639)

Comment: Though the question is of poor quality, I think I managed to provide a correct solution. See my answer.

Comment: I think you have a usability problem. If the caller was not the desired form, the button should be either disabled of invisible.

Comment: @bradbury9: Form2 would still probably need to know the form from which it was called to disable/hide the button.

Comment: Then, if it is not used in the constructor or the form, checking the property `Owner` would be OK https://stackoverflow.com/a/38469261/2265446

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to make more precise what you are asking.

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{   
    public static bool wasCalledFromForm1 = false;
    public Form2 (bool form1Called = false)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wasCalledFromForm1 = form1Called;
    }
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (wasCalledFromForm1) this.Close;
    }
}
```

Button 1 to open Form2:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(true);
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Form.Owner Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner?view=netframework-4.7.2).

**Form1:**

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog(this); // owner parameter
```

**Form2:**

```
if (this.Owner != null)
{ 
    // Owner is not null, there is a calling form
    // Do something
    if (this.Owner is Form1)
    {
       Form1 form1 = (Form1)this.Owner; // Form1 called this form!
    }
}
```

Comment: Take in mind it should not be checked in the constructor of the form, because it would not be asigned yet, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38469261/2265446

Comment: In OP's case he would want to use this in his button click event.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to know if there is a way to check if the showDialog has been called successfully or not, for that you can use the following code snippet:-

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
var result = frm.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // apply your logic
}
```

PS:- In future please compose your questions properly and carefully so that its easier for us to answer :) :) :)

Comment: This is not a correct answer - OP would have to write code to ensure the form returns that value. ShowDialog can return several different values & still have been called successfully - for example, if the form is closed by clicking the top left close button (as many people will do) the default return value is DialogResult.Cancel not DialogResult.OK.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @PaulF, since the question was not clear I didn't go to full length and check all the conditions, I was expecting some comment from the person asking the question, anyways I will retract or modify the answer once the question has been modified so that it can be understood properly :)

Answer (score 0):

A example with constructor.

```
form2 frm2 = new Form2(calledByFrm1: true);
frm2.ShowDialog();

// ...

class Form2 ... 
{
    boolean calledByForm1;

    public Form2(boolean calledByForm1) 
    {
        this.calledByForm1 = calledByForm1;
    }


    public Form2_Onload .... 
    {
        if (this.calledByForm1) 
        {
            // your logic here
        }
    }
}
```